# mySQL ORDER BY field with data

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to order a search by a field yet want to order via a value that exists in that field.

I have a field

```
image_name =
```

And that field is prefilled in with data

```
image_name = 'Image Name'
```

Users then go and update that field

```
image_name = 'Users Description'
```

I would like to order the search so that the prefilled in data is listed before the user filled in data.  I have fiddled around a bit, but havent managed to work it out.

Comment: The prefilled data is a constant value ?

Comment: SELECT ....... ORDER BY IF(image_name = 'Image Name',0,1),image_name;

Comment: Yes prefilled data is a constant across all unnamed images

Comment: What is the 0,1 in the IF statement

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the simple solution is to `ORDER BY image_name` because the 'Image Name' value will come first.

You can potentially get more creative and use a `case` in the `order by`.  For example:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN image_name = 'Image Name' THEN 1 
        WHEN image_name = 'Users Description' THEN 2
    END
```

Comment: Bernd Buffens solution above works perfectly, short and sweet.